# Fullcalendar Failure parsing JSON

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, nuxt.js, vuex

Im getting this error *Failure parsing JSON {message: "Failure parsing JSON", xhr: XMLHttpRequest}*

what I'm trying to do is

*get and display the events from an array that is store on a vuex file*
Im sure that something is missing or im using something wrong with fullcalendar

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <PageHeader :title="title" :items="items" />
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div>
              <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap'
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
        },

        plugins: [interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, bootstrapPlugin, listPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        nowIndicator: true,
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        dateClick: this.dateclick,
        events: "[events]",
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ events: 'appointments/EVENTS' }),
  },
}
</script>
```

vuex file /store --appointments.js

```js
//State
export const state = () => ({
  _events: [
  {
  title:"asdas",
  start:"2021-06-01",
  end:"2021-06-01",
  }
]
});

//Getters computed
export const getters = {
  EVENTS:(state)=> {
    return state._events;
  }
};
```

Comment: When is this error happening? Did you checked it `_events` is valid?

Comment: yes I do, a made a h1 with {{events}} from getters and its passing the data thats is on the _events array, and the error its happening when I load the page

Comment: Where does it error? It should give you the line. Everything is valid here so far.

Comment: this is the error main.js?d610:6214 Failure parsing JSON {message: "Failure parsing JSON", xhr: XMLHttpRequest}

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: what do you mean ? its coming from de console on the browser

Comment: In your code I mean.

Comment: im not sure I guess its on events:"[events]"

Comment: I would try to change it with some other JSON, try to comment parts of the code and alike to find out **exactly** what is buggy.

Comment: Im not using json, what im trying is to get that array that fullcalendar uses to pass my own data and dispaly it on the calendar

Comment: Alright, so after a clean formatting, I realized that you do have a strange `events:"[events]"` indeed. What does it even tries to do? It should be `events: this.events,` with `this.events` refering to the vuex getter.